# Firebase security rules protect list and public object

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

I have list of servers which has public access only if you have the key value.

Basically if user has object key, then he can retrive complete child object. but he should not be allowed to access list of objects.

Example of the object

```
{
    "servers": { // list of server

        // list should not be access directly - no anonymous access

        "key1": {  // this object can be access anonymously, if user knows the key
            "name": "linux"
            //...
        },

        "key2": {
            "name": "ubuntu"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make such security rule in firebase for above object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "servers": {
      "$serverid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since the root is not readable, `/servers` is also not readable and only once you have a `/servers/$serverid` does the read action become valid.

This and many similar topics are covered in the [Firebase guide on Security & Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/understanding-security.html).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought if you take away permission from the parent, then you can't revert that from a child. I will try and see how that goes.

Comment: It's the other way around: once you grant permission, you cannot take it away at a lower level.